# Colocar info de sql server en horizontal

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Muy Buenas, disculpen mi consulta es la siguiente tengo la siguiente informacion en  una consulta de sql server
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay alguna forma de colocar la misma informacion en una consulta que me la devuelva en horizontal por ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

toy buscando la forma de hacer un proceso con algun loop e ir creando columndas en una tabla temporal pero la verdad no se me ocurre como espero alguno pueda explicarme como o guiarme de que forma hacer el proceso

Comment: No entiendo bien que es lo que pretendes. Añadir más información al final como otras columnas? y de donde salen los datos añadidos?

Comment: Quieres tener una fila por cada combinación de supervisor, operario y fecha manteniendo el primer Id y generando múltiples columnas de Competencia y Valor?